# Why does this porting of C to PHP of Bubble Sort do not work?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I decided to create helper files for languages containing sorting algorithms ans searching algorithms. I started with C and wanted to make the adjacent in PHP. But the array I am passing is not getting sorted.
Why?

```
<?php
        function BubbleSort($array, $length)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < $length - 1; ++$i)
        {
            for($j = 0; $j < $length - $i - 1; ++$j)
            {
                if($array[$j] > $array[j + 1])
                {
                    $tmp = $array[$j];
                    $array[j] = $array[j + 1];
                    $array[j + 1] = $tmp;
                }
            }
        }


    }   

    $array = [5,2,3,1,2];
    $size = 5;

    print "Array is now: ";

    for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
    {
        print "{$array[$i]} ";
    }

    print "\n";

    BubbleSort($array, $size);

    for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
    {
        print "{$array[$i]} ";
    }

    print "\n";

    ?>
```

Comment: because you have syntax errors, namely $array[j + 1] try $array[$j + 1] perhaps.

Comment: There are better sorting algos built into PHP, are you aware of that?

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing array by reference, hence your function has to **return** the array and then you have to assign it back to the original array.

Provided there are no syntax errors otherwise, which honestly i didn't look at.

Comment: Yep just saw in your answer, those are on top of this problem

Comment: Yea, but I think it results in just a warning not a fatal error, in any case it messes the index all up.

Comment: Should I simply change the declaration of Bubble Sort to Bubble Sort(&$array, $lwngth)?

Comment: No, just return the sorted array.

Comment: Just return it and then assign it where you called. And yes you can do that too. Also you dont need to pass length you can calculate that within the function with `count($array)`

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors

Change

```
$array[j + 1]
```

To

```
$array[$j + 1]
```

Because php is loosely typed and other reasons this results in the j being seen as the constant j, and a warning level of something like ~ warning: unknown constant j assuming 'j', which treats it as a literal string of 'j' and then adds 'j' to 1, or something like that, that's just off the top of my head.